# NSTabView not showing tab bar items on top

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am trying to create a simple OSX app that has a split view (top to bottom). The second view of split view is a NSTabview having three tabs. Everything looks fine but NSTabview is not showing tabs bars (it is not tabless) however when i click around it works and switch to other tabs.

Comment: I think we'll need to see (some) code.  Not all of it please.

Comment: I do not have any backend code so far. Just xib though Outlets are there but does nothing. I will share code for sure.

Comment: Ok, figured it out. Inside drawRect of subclass of tab view invoked [super drawRect:dirtyRect]; and worked. Thanks.

Comment: You subclassed `NSTabView`?  That was an important missing detail.  Also I think it's unusual do subclass that control...

Comment: Yes, missed that will take care to include in future.